# Azure B2C For Both Web Apps and Native Mobile

Tags: android, ios, azure, azure-authentication

I am sure this scenario must be supported, but I cannot find examples of how to do it.

I have a .NET Core Web App that uses Azure AD B2C with custom html pages for signup, signin, profile edit, etc.

I would like to create some iOS and Android apps that interact with the same B2C tenant but provide their own native screens and just interact B2C from business logic.

Would the native apps just have to use the Microsoft Graph to log users in, reset passwords, edit profile, etc? Or can they use MSAL libraries (but not use the custom html pages defined in the policy flows) to drive their native authentication screens?

Comment: So you were unable to find: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android or https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android ?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'm asking if the custom html pages would necessarily be invoked if an Android or iOS app uses MSAL? Because if they are, then the only recourse for such native apps would be to use the Microsoft Graph instead of MSAL. I'm just looking to confirm that conclusion, because I cannot find any documentation that confirms it specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   They can surely use the MSAL libraries through various platforms in which the application code for the android and iOS apps is written, i.e., in **Java** and **Kotlin**. Also, MSAL libraries call **‘com.microsoft.identity.client’** as a dependency for initiating and incorporating Azure AD B2C identity and authorization through the application that makes an interactive authorization request callback. Please find the documentation link below and the code snippet from it which displays the use of MSAL libraries for authentication purposes.

This is the file code snippet to be added in the **‘AndroidManifest.xml’** file: -

```
  ‘ <!--Intent filter to capture System Browser or Authenticator calling back to our app after sign-in-->
    <activity
android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="msauth"
        android:host="Package_Name"
        android:path="/Signature_Hash" />
</intent-filter>
  </activity> ‘
```

Redirect URI: -

```
‘ msauth://com.azuresamples.msalandroidapp/1wIqXSqBj7w%2Bh11ZifsnqwgyKrY%3D ’
```

•   Please find below the link for Microsoft documentation that clearly states the use of **MSAL libraries** for authentication with Azure AD B2C: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-android-app?tabs=java

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-android-app?tabs=kotlin#step-5-configure-the-sample-mobile-app